# Show that $\mu_r = \mu_r' - \binom{r}{1} \mu'_{r-1} \cdot \mu + ... + (-1)^i \binom{r}{i} \mu'_{r-i} \cdot \mu^i$

Tags: statistics, solution-verification

Show that  $\mu_r = \mu_r' - \binom{r}{1} \mu'_{r-1} \cdot \mu + \cdots + (-1)^i \binom{r}{i} \mu'_{r-i} \cdot \mu^i + \cdots + (-1)^{r-1}(r-1)\cdot \mu^r$ for r = 1, 2, 3,,..., and use this formula to express $\mu_3$  in terms of moments.

Where $\mu_r = E[(X-\mu)^r]=\sum_x(x-\mu)^r \cdot f(x)$ which is the rth moment about the mean.

We also have
$$\frac{d^rM_X(t)}{dt^r}|_{t=0}=\mu'_r$$

I've tried expanding the expected value as $(X-\mu)^r=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{i+1} \binom{r}{i} \mu^rX^{r-i}$ so when $\mu_r$ I should get
$$(X-\mu)^3 = \sum_{i=0}^{3}(-1)^{i+1} \binom{r}{i} \mu^rX^{r-i}$$
for r = 3
$$\implies E[(X-\mu)^3] = E\left[(1)\binom{3}{0} \mu^3 +(-1)\binom{3}{1}\mu^2 X+(1)\binom{3}{2} \mu X^2+(-1)\binom{3}{3} X^3 \right]$$

$$\implies E[(X-\mu)^3] = E(X) - 2\mu E(X^2) +3\mu^2E(X)^3$$

I'm unsure as to whether this was the formula the question was asking for?

Comment: What is $\mu_i'$? What does "so when $\mu_r$" mean?

Comment: @TrevorGunn I've updated

Comment: Why not just say $\mu_i' = E(X^i)$? And certainly you want an $r!$ if you are defining it in terms of the moment generating function.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I'm not so sure where to go from here